# How can I download installation file for GRASS 7.2.0?

Tags: grass-7.2

I am trying to install GRASS 7.2.0 for my Windows 11, 64-bit laptop. However, I could not find setup file for it in the GRASS GIS website (it says, "Sorry, nothing's here"). There are download files for other versions, though. I am zero at programming or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot download GRASS 7.2.0 from the official website because it was removed from the download page.

[image]

But you can download using the wayback machine link: [WinGRASS-7.2.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20171102104254/https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/binary/mswindows/native/x86_64/WinGRASS-7.2.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe)

Comment: Thanks, Kadir. It really solved the issue. I downloaded the file and installed it.